# Accessing the user call when generating error messages

Tags: r, rlang

Consider the following example.

```r
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

foo <- function() {
  walk(1, \(i) {
    error()
  })
}

bar <- function() {
  error()
}

error <- function(call = caller_env()) {
  abort("Oops!", call = call)
}

foo()
# Error in `map()`:
# ℹ In index: 1.
# Caused by error in `.f()`:
# ! Oops!

bar()
# Error in `bar()`:
# ! Oops!
```

`foo()` doesn't give a very useful error message because, as opposed to `bar()`, it doesn't tell the user where the error happened.

The usual solution is to give `caller_env()` the exact number of calls to go back.

```
foo <- function() {
  walk("", \(i) {
    error(call = caller_env(4))
  })
}

foo()
# Error in `map()`:
# ℹ In index: 1.
# Caused by error in `foo()`:
# ! Oops!
```

This is however not very convenient because the number of calls to go back can vary greatly from a function to another, in particular when using nested functions or loops and alike.

Is there a simple solution to access user calls from `abort()` automatically without guessing the number of calls to go back?

The desired behavior is to print the function call from which the error occurred in the message, independently on how deep `error()` is in the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you - it does not fit in a comment (will remove if useless)... from what I understand the issue has to do with environments. The `purrr::map` call actually invokes multiple calls of a function (that is how I understand it ... could be wrong here), each working in / building its own environement but having access to the enviorment "above" it.

```
# set up the libraries and your error function
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

error <- function(call = caller_env()) {
    abort("Oops!", call = call)
}
```

If you run this function with a simple loop in it the error is "meaningfull":

```
foo <- function() {
    for (i in 1) {
        error()
    }
}

foo
Error in `foo()`:
! Oops!
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

From reading about `call_env()` I saw `current_env()` which we can hand down to the error function to get a more meaning full message:

```
foo <- function() {
    last_env <- current_env()
    purrr::walk(1, \(i) {
        error(last_env)
    })
}

foo()
Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `foo()`:
! Oops!
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

We can hand the error further down one defining a custom function which sets, or better, overwrites the last_env variable with the current enviornment.

```
myfun <- function(){
    last_env <- current_env()
    purrr::walk(1, \(i) {
        error(last_env)
    })
}
```

When we invoke this the error tells us the functino happened in the custom function:

```
foo <- function() {
    last_env <- current_env()
    myfun()
}

Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `myfun()`:
! Oops!
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Not lets call the custom function inside a `purrr` function call to see what we get:

```
foo <- function() {
   last_env <- current_env()
   purrr::walk(1, \(i) {
       myfun()
   })
}

foo()
Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `myfun()`:
! Oops!
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Also the information of "Error in 'map()'" and "i In index: 1." point to the `purrr::walk()` instance call (aka. list item) where the error happened, as this function is actually just a wrapper for `purrr::map()` (call "purrr::walk" in the console to confirm)

**EDIT**

Possibly the `tryCatch` approach works better:

```
# set up error function
error <- function(e) {
    paste("Oops!", e$call[1])
}
# custom function that throws error
foo <- function() {
    walk(1, \(i) {
        ssss
    })
}
# catch it applying custom error function
tryCatch(foo(), error = error)
[1] "Oops! map"


# encapsulate once
myfun <- function() {
    foo()
}
# encapsulate twice, catching inside
fo2 <- function() {
    tryCatch(myfun(), error = error)
}
# same error
fo2()
[1] "Oops! map"


# try to catch with one more encapsulatino
fo3 <- function() {
    myfun()
}
# still the correct error
tryCatch(fo3(), error = error)
[1] "Oops! map"
```

Comment: It's not a useless answer so please don't delete it. Although your solution of passing the current environment is interesting, it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. In fact, I'm making a package built around a few `R6` classes. Each public methods perform various argument checks returning an error if necessary. I find that passing the current environment or number of call to go back simply inconvenient. I'd prefer a way to get the user call from the function throwing the error directly (`error()` in the example above).

Comment: Actually, using `caller_env(sys.parent())` does what I want most of the time but I'm not sure if it's a good solution because it fails sometimes. Also it doesn't find the actual call when running unit tests for some reasons and usually simply return `Error in: blah blah` which I don't like.

Comment: @Junitar I have included some code with the tryCatch approach - not sure how it will behave on your usecase with R6 though

Comment: Actually the `tryCatch` approach doesn't print the right call. I'd expect `foo`, `fo2` and `fo3`.